# problem with `==` operator

Tags: c++, stl, queue

There is some class wComplex with `==` operator.

```
#ifndef WCOMPLEX_H
#define WCOMPLEX_H

#include <stdio.h>

// sample class of complex-like numbers with weird `==` operator
class wComplex{
private:
    double realPart;
    double imagePart;

public:
    wComplex();
    wComplex(double R);
    wComplex(double R, double I);
    bool operator==(wComplex &);
    void print();
};

wComplex::wComplex(){
    realPart  = 0;
    imagePart = 0;
}

wComplex::wComplex(double R){
    realPart  = R;
    imagePart = 0;
}

wComplex::wComplex(double R, double I)
{
    realPart  = R;
    imagePart = I;
}

bool wComplex::operator==(wComplex &El){
    double diff = realPart*realPart + imagePart*imagePart - 
    El.realPart*El.realPart - El.imagePart*El.imagePart;
    return (diff == 0);
}

void wComplex::print(){
    printf("(%g) + (%g)i\n", realPart, imagePart);
}   

#endif
```

It successfully worked with stuff like that:

```
wComplex A(1, 2);
wComplex B(2, 4);
wComplex C(2, 1);
```

(A==C) is true.

There is another class - queue-like. But it should control the new pushed element for equality (in `==` meaning) of other elements.

```
#ifndef MYQueue_H
#define MYQueue_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>


template<typename T>

class myQueue : public std::queue<T>{

public:

    myQueue(){
        printf("new myQueue successfully created\n");
    }

    void push (const T& x){
        myQueue* tmp = new myQueue;
        myQueue* old = new myQueue;
        old = this;
        bool MATCH = false;

        while(!old->empty()){
            T el = old->front();
            if(el == x){
                MATCH = true;
                tmp->push(x);
            }
            else
                tmp->push(el);
            old->pop();
        }
        if(!MATCH)
            tmp->push(x);
        this = *tmp;
        delete tmp;
        delete old;
    }

};

#endif
```

So, now there is one problem

```
myqueue.h: In member function ‘void myQueue<T>::push(const T&) [with T = wComplex]’:
shit.cpp:23:   instantiated from here
myqueue.h:26: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘el == x’
wcomplex.h:36: note: candidates are: bool wComplex::operator==(wComplex&)
myqueue.h:36: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

Actually, I can't understand why `no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘el == x’`
And what should I do? Any ideas

UPD: and how can I replace `this` element by `tmp`?
It's something wrong with `this = *tmp;`

Comment: I'm assuming el is meant to be an iterator and you have a typo in the declaration you have above.  If so then use `(*el) == x` ... your iterator does not have that operator defined the underlying object might if it is of the same type as T.  If de-referencing your iterator like above does not work than you have another problem most likely with the declaration of your queue.

Comment: Just a side note - comparing both complex numbers should be a lot easier to be done: `return realPart == El.realPart && imagePart == El.imagePart;` Otherwise 1 would be equal to i if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: @Mario It's just a weird sample of equal, not right

Comment: Ah, okay - really weird, indeed.

Comment: Remember not to use `==` when comparing `double` or `float`.  Instead, subtract and compare if less than a delta or `epsilon` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *const* reference to `T` in `push()` but your `operator==` only accepts non-const references.

```
bool wComplex::operator==(wComplex &El)
```

should be

```
bool wComplex::operator==(wComplex const &El) const
```

Or, optimally, your `operator==` should be a free function:

```
bool operator==(wComplex const & Left, wComplex const & Right) {
}
```

If you don't want outside access to the member variables of wComplex, you'll need to make the operator a friend function:

```
class wComplex {
...
    friend bool operator==(wComplex const & Left, wComplex const & Right);
...
};
```

EDIT: On the updated question:

You cannot assign to `this`. `this` is of type `T * const` - since it wouldn't make sense to modify it. What you're trying to do is to change an external variable which points to the current class, you cannot do that from inside a class member function unless this external variable is passed in as an argument.

I think you need to make a "queue" class which manages "node" class instances - trying to combine a container and the contained elements isn't really a good idea

Also, inheriting standard library containers is rarely a good idea. If you want to use a `std::queue` then make a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
bool wComplex::operator==(wComplex &El){
```

into:

```
bool wComplex::operator==(const wComplex &El) const {
```

Answer (score 0):

One tips for the future:

The const keyword, either you put it nowhere, or everywhere you can.

Obviously, everywhere you can is better.